# Why can't pictures using lightbox be saved?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, website, pictures

If you try and click on the round pillow on [this](http://thegallery-jane.com/l%C3%A6dervarer/puf/) website, then a larger version of the picture will zoom out.

I have seen this zoom out effect / box on other websites, where I also don't get the "Save Image As" or "View Background picture" in the right click menu.

Looking at the HTML I see the links to the thumb and the big size image

```
<a rel="lightbox" target="_blank" href=
"http://thegallery-jane.com/fotos/126977936/medium/1269779361.jpg"><img src=
"http://thegallery-jane.com/fotos/126977936/thumb/1269779361.jpg" style=
"width:113px;margin:5px;border:1px solid #555555;" alt="" title=
"Klik for at forst&oslash;rre" /></a><a rel="lightbox" target="_blank" href=
"http://thegallery-jane.com/fotos/126978330/medium/1269783307.jpg"><img src=
"http://thegallery-jane.com/fotos/126978330/thumb/1269783307.jpg" style=
"width:113px;margin:5px;border:1px solid #555555;" alt="" title=
"Klik for at forst&oslash;rre" /></a>
```

**Question**

Does there exist extensions or other means to easy save these pictures?

**Partly solution**

Disabling JavaScript gives the big size image when clicking on the thumb. It seams that lightbox puts a layer over the big size image to prevent the browser from "seeing" the image.

Comment: They are scaling a smaller version of the image. What you are trying to download is the original image.

Comment: Yes, it is the original I would like to save.

Comment: It is not scaled. See my updated OP.

Comment: Could try `Print Screen > Paste into MSPaint (or other image editing program) > crop as nessecary > save file as pillow.png`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution would be if an extension could be installed which would remove the invisible layer from the pictures.

But the easiest solution is probably to just <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and then find it in the Media list, or to install the JavaScript Toggle extension.

Comment: "The best solution would be if an extension could be installed which would remove the invisible layer from the pictures." - Your wish is our command. ;) See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Chrome, do right click>inspect element. It opens the page source, and you can explore it. Click on the item you want to inspect, and a line will highlight.

The photo you were looking for is here: [link](http://thegallery-jane.com/fotos/126978330/medium/1269783307.jpg)

However, I think clicking a link and save the photo link redirect to is a quite easy way.

Answer (score 2):

1. Here's the context menu when you right-click that zoomed image:

   [image: 1]
2. Install [Adblock Plus](http://adblockplus.org/en/firefox)
3. Open the Adblock Plus **Filter Preferences** dialog (via the menu or keyboard shortcut i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>):

   [image: 2]
4. Click on the **Custom Filters** tab, select the **Element Hiding Rules** section and click the **Add filter** button:

   [image: 3]
5. Now add the following rule: `thegallery-jane.com###stimuli_hoverNav` and close the dialog
6. Immediately you can see the change when you right-click that zoomed image now:

   [image: 4]

---

1. To identify the element to be hidden easily, install [Element Hiding Helper for Adblock Plus](http://adblockplus.org/en/elemhidehelper)
2. Launch the **Element Hiding Helper** (via the menu or keyboard shortcut i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>):

   [image: 5]
3. Use the mouse and element selection hotkeys such as **N**arrower or **W**ider (you'll get a help tooltip that lists them all) to focus on the element of interest:

   [image: 6]
4. Once you're sure that's the correct element simply click it and you'll see the following dialog, which allows you to further fine-tune the filter if required:

   [image: 7]
5. When you're done tweaking the filter click the **Add filter rule** button and it'll add the same filter for you automatically that you did manually in the top section.

**Important:** Please do *not* rip images wholesale from *any* site without the site/image copyright owner's explicit permission.

Comment: Thank you for this! I just stumbled upon some older image gallery where I had about a hundred images to save manually. On Chrome this works a bit different (and it could be different in Firefox these days too); just open up the Adblock Plus extension panel and select "Block an element", then carefully hover over the lightwidget image where it seemingly selects the whole image. Click and double-check that the URL of the element says `hoverNav` at the end and press OK.

Answer (score 0):

One solution if you don't mind to have "next prev" button is to put a little snippet:

$('.lb-nav').remove();

I looked at the source code and it does not have any option to disable it. So, i did this instead to change the source.